# Is either Geocentrism/Heliocentrism more "correct" than the other?

Tags: reference-frames, planets

Yesterday there was a casual discussion of the findings of the scientist Galileo in my German class. It was mentioned that his breakthrough was that, he found a convincing explanation that earth revolves around the sun in an ellipse rather than vice versa.

But is that actually a meaningful thing to say? Wouldn`t we get the equivalent answers whether we calculated physics in heliocentric or geocentric frame of refeerence ?

Comment: This has been asked before here IIRC... Yes, no frame is more correct than another. Usefulness (in certain aspects) is a different story, though.

Comment: Its more a point of how the universe works and what role we (as humans) play. Yes, the fact that its true that one can choose any reference frame and get the same (physical) answers is a key concept. But this implies in particular that the earth and us humans don't stand as some extraordinary object within the universe.

Comment: Of course this also implies that in some reference frame, where we are "inertial" (for gallileo the fixed stars frame) the acceleration of the sun is much smaller than that of the earth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If reference frames are equally valid, then why do teachers say the geocentric view is wrong?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728129/if-reference-frames-are-equally-valid-then-why-do-teachers-say-the-geocentric-v) and links therein

Comment: [An explanation](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2898:_Orbital_Argument) of a recent relevant _xkcd_ comic.